# Why am I only getting one take! from this channel?

Tags: clojure

Trying to understand how channels work; I don't get why my `take!` only works once in this REPL sequence, even though I try multiple puts along the way:

```
cplay.core> (def h (chan))
#'cplay.core/h
cplay.core> (go (put! h "hello"))
#<ManyToManyChannel clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel@4afdd6ba>
cplay.core> (go (take! h (fn [x] (println x))))
#<ManyToManyChannel clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel@9fe39a1>
cplay.core> hello

cplay.core> (go (take! h (fn [x] (println x))))
#<ManyToManyChannel clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel@206564e9>
cplay.core> (go (put! h "hello"))
#<ManyToManyChannel clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel@6c0ec468>
cplay.core> (go (take! h (fn [x] (println x))))
#<ManyToManyChannel clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel@60c85184>
cplay.core> (go (take! h (fn [x] (println x))))
#<ManyToManyChannel clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel@3edc08c3>
cplay.core> (go (take! h (fn [x] (println x))))
#<ManyToManyChannel clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel@6a7b295f>
cplay.core> (go (put! h "hello"))
#<ManyToManyChannel clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel@60331d8b>
cplay.core> (go (take! h (fn [x] (println x))))
#<ManyToManyChannel clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel@557c3bce>
cplay.core> (go (put! h "hello"))
#<ManyToManyChannel clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel@203fdcfb>
cplay.core> (go (put! h "hello"))
#<ManyToManyChannel clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel@ed11c1>
cplay.core> (go (take! h (fn [x] (println x))))
#<ManyToManyChannel clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel@6c7ea146>
cplay.core>
```

Is it because I then take from the channel several times in succession when nothing is on the channel, thereby leaving "voids" that are filled by subsequent puts until the channel somehow gets back to and even number of puts and takes?

Comment: Is this your real output? I would expect the second `(fn [x] (println x)` part to run and output `hello` once you called `(go (put! h "hello"))` a second time since calling `take!` on an "empty" channel blocks until a message arrives.

Comment: @sloth yes this is copied from my REPL exactly

Comment: I can't reproduce this with core.async 0.1.303.0-886421-alpha. Which version are you using?

Comment: @sloth yes I'm using the absolute latest version as of today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The println behavior is quiet weird in this async scenario. 
If your last invocation is the "take!" fn then you'll end up with the print result in your repl, but is four last invocation is the "put!" fn  then you have to find the print result on the nrepl-server terminal.

This behavior and necessary workspace it's introduced on the beginning of [Timothy Baldridge video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=enwIIGzhahw) of core.async

And here [one screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8688858/emacs.png) of my 2 frames in emacs, one for the nrepl and the other for the nrepl-server output

Comment: Wouldn't you know, I switched over to my nrepl buffer in Emacs and there they all were.

Comment: anyway @edbond is right noting you that it's not necessary to use the go macro for using take! and put!

Answer (score 0):

Don't wrap `put!` and `take!` with `go`. Inside go you want `<!` or `!>`:

```
user=> (require '[clojure.core.async :refer (chan put! take! <! >!)])
nil
user=> (def h (chan))
#'user/h
user=> (put! h "hello")
true
user=> (take! h println)
hello
nil
user=> (put! h "hello")
true
user=> (take! h println)
hello
nil
user=> (put! h "hello")
true
user=> (take! h println)
hello
nil
user=> (put! h "hello")
true
user=> (take! h println)
hello
nil
user=> (take! h println)
nil
user=> (put! h "hello")
hello
true
```

Comment: But if you look at the docs the shortened corner bracket form in its simplest arity is the same as the more verbose spelling

Comment: `put!` is roughly equivalent to `(go (>! ...))`, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/20927927/1362000